# Android EMM Minimum Version Not Updating Application

Tags: android-management-api

Using the EMM API I've set the minimum version to 10 and the current version of the application installed on the device is 9. I've also set the update policy to be high priority. I was expecting the application to be automatically updated. However, instead of being updated a warning is shown on the screen saying if the application is not updated the device will be erased. The application is running in Kiosk mode.

The application is a 'private' application in the play store.

The policy looks like:

```
{"name": "enterprises/LC03fyux1e/policies/staging-ben",
  "version": "7",
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "io.teller.droid.staging",
      "installType": "KIOSK",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "managedConfiguration": {
      ...
      },
      "minimumVersionCode": 10,
      "autoUpdateMode": "AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY"
    }
  ],
  "screenCaptureDisabled": true,
  "cameraDisabled": true,
  "systemUpdate": {
    "type": "WINDOWED",
    "startMinutes": 120,
    "endMinutes": 240
  },
  "addUserDisabled": true,
  "adjustVolumeDisabled": true,
  "factoryResetDisabled": true,
  "mountPhysicalMediaDisabled": true,
  "modifyAccountsDisabled": true,
  "safeBootDisabled": true,
  "uninstallAppsDisabled": true,
  "statusBarDisabled": true,
  "keyguardDisabled": true,
  "statusReportingSettings": {
    "applicationReportsEnabled": true,
    "deviceSettingsEnabled": true,
    "softwareInfoEnabled": true,
    "memoryInfoEnabled": true,
    "networkInfoEnabled": true,
    "displayInfoEnabled": true,
    "powerManagementEventsEnabled": true,
    "hardwareStatusEnabled": true,
    "systemPropertiesEnabled": true,
    "commonCriteriaModeEnabled": true
  },
  "bluetoothContactSharingDisabled": true,
  "bluetoothConfigDisabled": true,
  "credentialsConfigDisabled": true,
  "tetheringConfigDisabled": true,
  "vpnConfigDisabled": true,
  "createWindowsDisabled": true,
  "networkResetDisabled": true,
  "outgoingBeamDisabled": true,
  "outgoingCallsDisabled": true,
  "removeUserDisabled": true,
  "shareLocationDisabled": true,
  "smsDisabled": true,
  "unmuteMicrophoneDisabled": true,
  "usbFileTransferDisabled": true,
  "ensureVerifyAppsEnabled": true,
  "stayOnPluggedModes": [
    "AC",
    "USB"
  ],
  "setUserIconDisabled": true,
  "setWallpaperDisabled": true,
  "locationMode": "LOCATION_DISABLED",
  "networkEscapeHatchEnabled": true,
  "bluetoothDisabled": true,
  "funDisabled": true,
  "appAutoUpdatePolicy": "ALWAYS",
  "skipFirstUseHintsEnabled": true,
  "advancedSecurityOverrides": {
    "untrustedAppsPolicy": "DISALLOW_INSTALL",
    "googlePlayProtectVerifyApps": "VERIFY_APPS_ENFORCED",
    "developerSettings": "DEVELOPER_SETTINGS_ALLOWED",
    "commonCriteriaMode": "COMMON_CRITERIA_MODE_DISABLED"
  },
  "autoDateAndTimeZone": "AUTO_DATE_AND_TIME_ZONE_ENFORCED"
}
```

Important note: The policy shown here appears to work. The policy where it was not working included 'installAppsDisabled: true'. It seems like if you disable installing apps with the policy then this also prevents automatically updating applications.

Comment: Can you give me more information about your issue like the implementation of the policy being used and the application you're trying to update. 
You also need to double check if the app you’re trying to update is already updated to version 10 in google play in order for it to auto update on your device.

Comment: This dialog that says the device will be erased allows you to manually update the application and I am able to do that so the problem is not the version is unavailable in the play store. Also, after this 'manual' update the erase dialog no longer shows.